# "No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgr24" when using OpenCV with FFMPEG on mac

Tags: macos, video, opencv, ffmpeg, osx-lion

When trying to acquire a frame from a video file (I've tried several video formats) I am getting an error message "No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgr24".
The exact same code ran perfectly fine on a windows machine and I couldn't get it to run on a mac even after I recompiled and installed FFMPEG and OpenCV. I am using lion for my OS.
Any ideas?

Comment: http://alexsleat.co.uk/2011/01/09/how-to-fix-no-accelerated-colorspace-conversion-found-from-yuv420p-to-bgr24-opencv-2-2-0-ubuntu-10-10/

Answer (score -1):

OpenCV uses a specific video coding/decoding back-end for each OS. On windows, it uses ffmpeg, which in turn can use some codecs installed on the machine. On Mac it uses qTime, and I think it can be compiled with ffmpeg.

Make sure u have quickTime up-to-date, and maybe install some codecs (There is such a notion on Mac?)

Hope it helps!